# Bootstrap children element height 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, height

I want a Button, with 2 elements in it, to slide the Background.

But I want both elements to center vertical and get height 100% even when the other element is bigger.

Here is the HTML

```
<button class="btn-cstm-slide">
    <div class="btn-cstm-slide-logo"><span>Test Test 14343</span></div>
    <div class="btn-cstm-slide-text">
        <span>Just a Testtest</span>
        <br/>
        <span>Let's see</span>
    </div>
</button>
```

And here the CSS

```
    .btn-cstm-slide {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333C42;

    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.btn-cstm-slide-logo {
    height:100%;

    min-height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #474f54;
    color: #fff;
}
.btn-cstm-slide-text {
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #333C42;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.btn-cstm-slide-text * {
    position:relative;
}

.btn-cstm-slide-text:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    background-color: #474f54;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.btn-cstm-slide-text:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Demo**

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/e07uc4kj/1/)

Can you help me? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

https://jsfiddle.net/e07uc4kj/9/

```
.btn-cstm-slide {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #333C42;

    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.btn-cstm-slide-logo {
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #474f54;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.btn-cstm-slide-text {
    margin-left: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #333C42;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.btn-cstm-slide-text:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    background-color: #474f54;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.btn-cstm-slide-text:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: No, I don't need fixed width.
Is there no option that is dynamic? :/

Comment: @CutmastaD Can you set a fixed height for the button? https://jsfiddle.net/bnb0Lswu/

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I worked something out, but the height of the smaller div doesn't get 100% of the parents height: https://jsfiddle.net/e07uc4kj/12/

Comment: You can't set a fixed height or a fixed width? Could you please explain in more detail what exactly the constraints are here? Are you open to Javascript?

Comment: There are nor constraints, I just want a Button which width and height are dynamic depending on his content. And I'm open to Javascript, but there has to be a easy CSS solution :D

Comment: Dynamic Height and Dynamic Width ARE constraints. That said, my recommendation then becomes to use my original answer, remove the width and margin definitions, then use jQuery to calculate the width of .btn-cstm-slide-logo and set the left margin of .btn-cstm-slide-text accordingly.

Comment: @CutmastaD if this answer helped you I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the solution, if not could you please let me know what you're struggling with so that I can assist you further?